# Word that includes mythology, legends, etc.?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, nouns, metonyms

I am searching for a word or short phrase that includes/describes following words:

- myth/mythology
- legends
- mythos
- lore
- fable
- saga

I know I am not really precise with what I am searching for.
I am not even sure if such a word exists.

Comment: Fiction, perhaps?

Comment: Ethos ..........

Comment: For this kind of question, it's better to look in a [thesaurus](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/myth?s=t) rather than posting here. If you do that and still can't find a word that fits, then you can ask here, but be sure to follow the instructions for [single word requests](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are all subsets of 'stories', although 'folklore', or even simply 'lore', is probably more accurate to your needs. I know you mentioned -lore, and I assume you refer to 'folklore' type words, but I think it would cover your bases.

Answer (score 0):

Although it has a denigratory overtone, you might consider "mumbo-jumbo", which Webster's defines as "an object of superstitious homage and fear".

Usage example: "We sure have come a long way from myths, legends, and mumbo jumbo our ancestors relied on to explain the natural world..."

http://www.southeastflyfishingforum.com/forum/anyone-seen-mountain-lion-t12962.html?s=28b3fdbc7fd39964f8efc344c29c6973&p=366642